# What is the real meaning of transformIgnorePatterns in Jest configuration?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In Jest we can configure `transformIgnorePatterns` to ignore files to be transpiled, which defaults to `"/node_modules/"`. However, if a dependency is not translated when it is published, such as `/node_modules/atest`, according to the instructions on the official website, it should be configured to `transformIgnorePatterns`, which feels contrary to the "ignored" meaning of this configuration.

I want to know which files are translated and which files are ignored and not translated by pressing the configuration file below.

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/atest']
    // ...
}
```

Possible answer 1: Dependencies in `node_modules` except `atest` are transpiled

Possible answer 2: Only `atest` in `node_modules` is transpiled, the rest of the dependencies are not transpiled

Answer (score 9):

From the doc, the [transformIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) option has default value: `["/node_modules/", "\\.pnp\\.[^\\\/]+$"]`

It means:

> If the file path matches any of the patterns, it will **not** be transformed.

So, the packages inside the `node_modules` directory will  **NOT** be transformed by default.

Now, you have a package named `atest` which is not a pre-compiled package, you need to transform it using `babel` and don't transform other packages inside `node_modules`. So the configuration should be:

```js
{
  "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!(atest)/)"]
}
```

Test paths:

```
/node_modules/atest/index.js
/node_modules/react/index.js
/node_modules/lodash/index.js
/node_modules/dayjs/index.js
```

The `/node_modules/atest` will be excluded from `transformIgnorePatterns` configuration which means it will be transformed.

See the regexp [test](https://regex101.com/r/nNZRen/1)

Comment: I agree with OP that it's confusing. But based on your answer, the property ignores all packages in node_modules. In practical usage, we want to indicate which files to include. The key here being that `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. So essentially... we want to ignore the following files: "everything in node_modules except for atest".

Comment: If there are multiple node packages that need excluding they have to be mentioned in the same regex. So `["/node_modules/(?!(atest|other-package)/)"]` works but not `["/node_modules/(?!(atest)/)", ["/node_modules/(?!(other-package)/)"]`.